Scraping encoded data from Oddsportal
Oddsportal.com provides odds data from several betting sites. I've been scraping the data for years but they have recently encoded their data and I haven't found a way to decode it.
Example: https://www.oddsportal.com/football/england/premier-league/liverpool-manchester-city-82qTWLi3/#1X2;2
The odds data is automatically updated and the data is retrieved from: https://www.oddsportal.com/feed/match-event/1-1-82qTWLi3-1-2-yj30c.dat (the XXX in yjXXX.dat may sometimes change)
The read data should be in json format.
The following Python script reads the data (some headers might not be mandatory):
import urllib.request

url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/feed/match-event/1-1-82qTWLi3-1-2-yjdca.dat'

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.oddsportal.com',
    'method': 'GET',
    'scheme': 'https',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-encoding': 'deflate',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fi-FI;q=0.8,fi;q=0.7',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'referer': 'https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/hockey/20240109',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)

text = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8')

print(text[:80])

print('string length:', len(text))

Output:
NFBSamc0SmVBREJnQVgwMm9Ld0IwMll1VXNBVEYyckdONHJnL3ljUEtYSjlJVDZ5Q0ZWNmlkeWcxYnJy
string length: 187240

Any ideas how to decode the data?

I'd like to hear from close voters how this question could be improved. It provides a very specific example of this case, and obfuscated* APIs are common enough to be of general interest. (*obfuscated as in "encrypted" so that you can't merely open dev tools and read the response of a request, but not-really-encrypted because the key is of course included in the javascript so that the browser can read it)

So basicly your json request url is build up like this. You load it like you should do normal, with headers. Make sure in the headers you
have 'referer': 'https://www.oddsportal.com/' and 'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'  besides normal headers.
import requests
import json
import base64    
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes import SHA256
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

# URL for fetching the data
url = f'https://www.oddsportal.com/feed/match-event/{version_id}-{sport_id}-{unique_id}-1-2-{xhash}.dat'

# Send the GET request and retrieve the response text
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = response.text

# Decode the base64 encoded data
decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data).decode()

# Separate the encrypted data and key
encrypted, key = decoded_data.split(":")

# Decode the encrypted part and the key
encrypted_bytes = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(encrypted)
key_bytes = bytes.fromhex(key)

# Define the password and salt used for key derivation
password = b"%RtR8AB&nWsh=AQC+v!=pgAe@dSQG3kQ"
salt = b"orieC_jQQWRmhkPvR6u2kzXeTube6aYupiOddsPortal"

# Derive the AES key using PBKDF2 with SHA256
kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
    algorithm=SHA256(),
    length=32,  # 256 bits
    salt=salt,
    iterations=1000,
    backend=default_backend()
)

aes_key = kdf.derive(password)

# Set up the AES decryption cipher in CBC mode
cipher = Cipher(
    algorithms.AES(aes_key),
    modes.CBC(key_bytes),
    backend=default_backend()
)
decryptor = cipher.decryptor()

# Decrypt the data
decrypted_bytes = decryptor.update(encrypted_bytes) + decryptor.finalize()

# Decode the decrypted bytes into a string
decrypted_data = decrypted_bytes.decode('utf-8')

# Find the end of the JSON data
end_of_json = decrypted_data.rfind('}')

# If a valid JSON end is found, trim the data to that point
if end_of_json != -1:
    decrypted_data = decrypted_data[:end_of_json + 1]

# Parse the decrypted data as JSON
try:
    parsed_data = json.loads(decrypted_data)
    print(parsed_data)
except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
    print("Error parsing JSON:", e)

Whenever the app.js file is updated, the password might change. To find the password and salt values, you can use your browser's inspector. Navigate to the Sources tab, locate the app.js file under res/public, then the js folder, and finally the build folder. The file is named something like app.js?v=241219130943. Once you inspect this file, you can use the search function to look for h(r.data,
The values following this string are your password and salt, separated by a comma. Make sure you also use the quotation marks.
Please let me know if it worked for you.

I'm not sure how this ended up in the Very Low Quality queue, but it's not. Wrong answers are not Very Low Quality (even if they have no correct information at all). If you feel that the answer is wrong or won't help solve the problem, you should vote and comment accordingly (but again, it's not Very Low Quality).

@folengateis I don't think it's AI plagiarism (the spelling/grammar and style are different than what I'd expect from a ChatGPT-plagiarized answer).

I am not a bot. This script works. I just wanted to help the original poster as is was experiencing the same problem.

@folengateis "the chances of deciphering anything with a hash function are nil" The browser does it, so why do you say the chances are nil? The mere involvement of a hash function doesn't mean anything.

@Juiced This answer could be improved with an explanation on where in the source you found the values for password and salt, so that OP can figure them out if they change.

@folengateis The browser runs the javascript code that figures out what to show the user based on the obfuscated data from the API. This means that there is a way to figure out the data based on the javasript code and the obfuscated data from the API. I don't understand why you seem to be obsessed about the fact that hash functions are involved.

@folengateis Where did you get the idea that something in this answer is "deciphered with a hash function"? That looks like you're just putting familiar words together.

For what it's worth, taking headers from OP and version_id, sport_id, unique_id and xhash from the example URL given by OP, this answer actually returns the deobfuscated JSON data. Code: https://pastebin.com/sYPpNXM3 Output: https://pastebin.com/kn81bjc8

alright i'm an ass
